# How can I install Ubuntu 18.04 in my D drive which is my main disk?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to install Ubuntu on Virtual Box which running on Windows.

My C drive  118GB (Windows 10 is there.)

My D drive 900GB( It's almost empty.)

My question is:

Can I install both Ubuntu and Virtual Box in my D drive? I don't want to lose my datas.Because I want to use both(Windows & Ubuntu) , can it be a problem for different disks?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Can you specify: do you want to install Ubuntu alongside with Windows or you want to install Ubuntu on Virtual Box which running on Windows?

Comment: @MaksymM. Second one. I want to install Ubuntu on Virtual Box which running on Windows

Comment: You can install VB machines anywhere you like.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu on Virtualbox is very safe for your data, almost no chance of oops.  Do not think you can install virtualbox on D drive though(maybe).  If C drive almost full can probably take space from D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox is standard software that installs the VirtualBox software to run VMs into your computer.  From there, you create a VM and direct the storage to be stored on the "D" drive.  That's all within Windows and plain file storage, has nothing to do with 'installing to the D drive' as a dual-boot would do.

You will lose no files, and you will not have any impact on your system in terms of file storage or loss of data (unless your hard drive dies or something, but that's a completely different issue).  Preferably you would create a directory inside your D drive to hold all the VM bits/components for that given VM, and install direct to the VM from there.